# Hidden form not closing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In VB.NET when I try to close the hidden form using `form.close()`, `form_FormClosed` and `Form_FormClosing` events are not triggered.
but when the hidden form in `VB6` code is closed (using form.unload()), `form_unload` event triggers properly.

I have used below sample code in VB.NET desktop application :

**Form1**:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles Command1.Click
    
    Form2.ShowDialog()
    MsgBox("show next line")
    Form2.Close()
    MsgBox("after close")    
End Sub
```

**Form2**:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles Command1.Click
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
            
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox("form 2 load")        
End Sub
    
Public Sub Form2_FormClosed(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    MsgBox("form 2 unload")
End Sub
```

**Note**: In VB.NET if I use `Form.Select()` before calling `Form.Close()` then Form closes properly.

Is there any other way to close the form properly when it is hidden or selecting the form is the correct method?

Comment: Dialogs are special.  After closing the form, ShowDialog() returns and you'd normally next retrieve the dialog properties.  So the first bug in the code is ignoring the ShowDialog() method's return value, you need to know if the user closed the form normally or (as here) it got dismissed without completing the dialog.  Next bug is the one you complain about, the FormClosed event doesn't fire until the form object gets disposed, signaling that you're done using the dialog properties.  Strongly favor the `Using` statement.  Or perhaps you really meant to use Show() instead.

Comment: Why would you be hiding a dialogue in the first place? It's very unlikely that you have a workflow where that's a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: you cannot close your hidden form if you are using `.ShowDialog()`. well you can but it will also close the dialog you just show and terminate all its processes; I think you need to use `.Show()` instead of showdialog. keep in mind that hidden forms are still eating your ram;